Expected number of flips until HH
I am looking for some help figuring out what is wrong with my approach.
To obtain HH, it requires flipping until a head is obtained, and then needing another head. But if it is tails, then it starts over again waiting for the first head.
Let

$W_i$ be the number of flips to get the first head in a run

These are independent, and are geometric with $p=\frac{ 1 }{ 2 }$ for a fair coin


$W_{HH}$ be the number of flips to get HH

This can be expressed as $W_{HH} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N W_i + 1$ where $N$ is the number of runs, so $W_{HH}$ is the sum of a random number of RVs
The number of runs $N$ can be viewed as $\operatorname{Geom}(\frac{ 1 }{ 2 })$ because following the H of each run, there can either be H which is a success, or a T which is a failure, and therefore the number of runs corresponds exactly to the number of times this oppurtunity to terminate occurs, until we finally get a H



For example, for the outcome $TTH \;\; T_F TTH \;\; T_F TH \;\; H_S$ we would have $W_1 = 3, W_2 = 4, W_3 = 3, N=3$  (where the F and S subscripts represent the trials that determine $N$)
Then $E[W_{HH}] = E [ E[W_{HH} | N]] = E[ 2N + 1] = 5$

because $E[W_{HH} | N=n] = n E[W_1] + 1 = 2n+1$
and $E[N] = 2$

However the answer should be 6?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924996/27978 for an approach.

@BrianMoehring Ah thank you that is right

Note that $N=n \iff W_2, W_3, \ldots, W_n \neq 1$ and $W_{n+1} = 1$.  That is, once you condition on $N$, these $N-1$ random variables ($W_i$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$) are no longer geometric with $p=1/2$ but rather of the form $1+X$ where $X$ is geometric with $p=1/2$ [show this].
As a result, $$\mathbb{E}[W_{HH} \mid N ] = 2N + 1 + (N-1) = 3N.$$
We then have $\mathbb{E}[W_{HH}] = \mathbb{E}[3N] = 6$.

Somewhat alternative approach:
Flipping stops on two consecutive heads.  Prior to that there are two possible statuses that you can be in.

Status-0 
Either the last flip was tails, or there have not been any coins flipped yet.

Status-1 
Either the last two coin flips were tails-heads, or there has been exactly 1 coin flip, which has been a heads.


For $~k \in \{0,1\},~$ let $~E(k)~$ denote the expected number of coin flips, from this point forward, until two consecutive heads are reached, assuming that you are in Status-k.
Then:
$$E(0) = 1/2[E(1) + 1] + 1/2[E(0) + 1] \implies $$
$$2E(0) = E(1) + E(0) + 2 \implies $$
$$E(0) - 2 = E(1).$$
Then:
$$E(1) = 1/2[1] + 1/2[E(0) + 1] \implies $$
$$2[E(0) - 2] = 2E(1) = E(0) + 2 \implies $$
$$E(0) = 6.$$



$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Alternative (somewhat inferior) approach, that uses an infinite sequence.
For $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ let

$g(n)~$ denote the number of coin flip sequences of length $~n,~$ where there has been no occurrence of consecutive heads anywhere in the $~n~$ coin flips.

$h(n)~$ denote the number of coin flip sequences of length $~n,~$ where the very first occurrence of consecutive heads anywhere in the $~n~$ coin flips is on the last two coin flips.


To reach 2 consecutive heads, the probability of it taking

2 coin flips : 1/4.

3 coin flips : 1/8.


Then, the overall expected number of coin flips is
$$(2 \times 1/4) + (3 \times 1/8) + \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left[ ~2^{-n} \times n \times h(n) ~\right]. \tag1 $$
The following (somewhat convoluted) analysis creates a closed form formula for $~g(n),~$ and then links $~g(n)~$ to $~h(n).$

Let

$g(n,0)~$ denote the number of n length sequences where there has been no occurrence of two consecutive heads and the last coin flip was tails.

$g(n,1)~$ denote the number of n length sequences where there has been no occurrence of two consecutive heads and the last coin flip was heads.


Then:

$g(n) = g(n,0) + g(n,1).~$

$g(n,0) = g(n-1).$

$g(n,1) = g(n-1,0) = g(n-2).$


So, $~g(n) = g(n-1) + g(n-2),~$ where :

$g(1) = 2.$
$g(2) = 3.$
$g(3) = 5.$

Letting $~\langle F_n\rangle ~$ denote the fibonacci sequence
$~\langle ~1,1,2,3,5,\cdots ~\rangle,~$ you have that $~g(n) = F_{n+2}.$
To enumerate $~h(n),~$ note that you need a sequence of length $~n-3,~$ with no consecutive heads, followed specifically by tails, heads, heads.
Therefore,
$$h(n) = g(n-3) = F_{n-1}.$$
Therefore, the overall expected number of coin flips is
$$\frac{7}{8} + \sum_{n=4}^\infty \left[ ~2^{-n} \times n \times F_{n-1} ~\right], \tag2 $$
where the closed form formula for $~F_n~$ is
$$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left[ ~\left( ~\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} ~\right)^n - \left( ~\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} ~\right)^n ~\right].$$
The expression in (2) above can be re-written as
$$\frac{7}{8} 
\\+ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}} ~\sum_{n=4}^\infty \left[ n \times ~\left( ~\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^{n-1} ~\right] \\
- \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}} ~\sum_{n=4}^\infty~\left[ n \times ~\left( ~\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^{n-1} ~\right]. \tag3 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to showing that the expression in (3) above equals $~6.~$

Note that for $~|x| < 1,~$ that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}, ~~~~\sum_{n=0}^\infty n ~x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+4)x^{n+3}$$
$$= x^3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+4)x^n
= x^3 \left[ ~\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{4}{1 - x} ~\right]$$
$$= x^3 ~\frac{x + 4(1-x)}{(1-x)^2} 
= \frac{x^3 (4 - 3x)}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Also, note that

$\displaystyle \left( ~\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^3 = \frac{2 + \sqrt{5}}{8},$ 
$\displaystyle \left( ~\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^3 = \frac{2 - \sqrt{5}}{8}.$

$\displaystyle 4 - \frac{3(1 + \sqrt{5})}{4} = \frac{13 - 3\sqrt{5}}{4}$ 
$\displaystyle 4 - \frac{3(1 - \sqrt{5})}{4} = \frac{13 + 3\sqrt{5}}{4}.$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\left( ~1 - \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^2} = 14 + 6\sqrt{5},$ 
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\left( ~1 - \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right)^2} = 14 - 6\sqrt{5}.$


Therefore, the expression in (3) above is equivalent to
$$\frac{7}{8}$$
$$+ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}} \left[ ~\left( ~\frac{2 + \sqrt{5}}{8} ~\right) ~\left( ~\frac{13 - 3\sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right) ~\left( ~14 + 6\sqrt{5} ~\right) ~\right] $$
$$- \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}} \left[ ~\left( ~\frac{2 - \sqrt{5}}{8} ~\right) ~\left( ~\frac{13 + 3\sqrt{5}}{4} ~\right) ~\left( ~14 - 6\sqrt{5} ~\right) ~\right] $$
$$= \frac{7}{8} + \frac{364 + 164\sqrt{5}}{64\sqrt{5}} - \frac{364 - 164\sqrt{5}}{64\sqrt{5}} = 6.$$

Here's a general formula that should help
Let E(n) be the expected # of tosses for  a run of n for an experiment with a probability of a single sucess being p
Then after a run of $(n-1)$, one toss either takes us to our goal, or with probability $(1-p)$, we are back at start.
Thus ${E(n) = 1 + E(n-1) + (1-p)E(n)}$
which reduces to $\Large{\boxed{E(n) = \frac1{p}[1+E(n-1)]}}$
By the geometric distribution, $E(1) = 2$
Thus $E(2) = 2(1+2) = 6$
With this formula, for instance, you immediately get the expected # of tosses for two consecutive $6's$ in rolls of a $D6 \; as\; 6(1+6) = 42$
